# Remove the characters from string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
SubClient          Status
POD5_vcprd01
POD4_vcprd01
POD15_VCPRD01_New
POD11_2_vcprd01
POD11_1_vcprd01
POD12_vcprd01
POD13_vcprd01_new
POD10_vcprd01_NEW
```

I am trying to remove `_new` & `_New` from the above table which is in CSV. I wrote the below script:

```
$report = @()
$Pod_SC = Import-csv "above table"

foreach($Podclient in $pod_sc)
{
$Client = $Podclient.Subclient
$Subclient = $Client.Substring(0,$Client.IndexOf('_N'))
$Status = $Podclient.Status 

$object = New-Object -TypeName PSobject

$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subclient" -Value $SubClient

$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value $Status

$report += $object
}
```

But its not working. the expected output is

```
SubClient          Status
POD5_vcprd01
POD4_vcprd01
POD15_VCPRD01
POD11_2_vcprd01
POD11_1_vcprd01
POD12_vcprd01
POD13_vcprd01
POD10_vcprd01
```

Comment: Why don't you just replace with "" ?

Comment: `(Get-Content $file) -replace '_new' | Set-Content $file`

Comment: Thanks. it works

Answer (score 0):

Just treat it as a text replace, if you use `ireplace` which is case-insensitive you can deal with both `_New` and `_new` together.

```
(Get-Content file.csv) -ireplace "_new","" | Set-Content file.csv
```

You can actually use just `-ireplace "_new"`, but if you wanted to replace rather than remove the syntax is the same as in my example `-ireplace "_new","_old"`

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: PowerShell is case-insensitive by default, so `-ireplace` and `-replace` do the same.